# Text widget won't show result from class

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project I have a class which makes a calculation, and then returns it in a list of strings. When trying to show the result of the class in a Text widget later in my code, nothing is displayed. I think it might be a problem with either what the function returns, or something going wrong when I try to call the class. I tried running print() and logger.d() statements in the class, but nothing is shown in the terminal.

The class should return a list of strings, but when trying to retrieve this List at an index, nothing is displayed by the Text widget.

I tried running print() and logger.d() statements in the class to figure out where each variable had what value, so I could track issues down, but they never showed in my vs code terminal, which leads me to believe it is an issue with calling the class.

I tried Google, ChatGPT, asking my rubber ducky, running debugger and peers, but you guys are my last resort, as none of them could help. (ChatGPT didn't even understand list.lenght > 2).

Here is the code:

````
class OptiTijdCalculator {
  List<String> calculateOptiTijd(double uren) {
    String optiTijdStart = "";
    String optiTijdEind = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < HourlyResults.length - 24; i++) {
      List<double> j = [];
      j.add(HourlyResults[i].result);
      if (j.length > uren - 1) {
        double sum1 = j.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        List<double> j2 = List<double>.from(j);
        j2.add(HourlyResults[i + 1].result);
        j2.removeAt(0);
        double sum2 = j2.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        if (sum1 > sum2) {
          optiTijdStart = HourlyResults[i - 7].dateTime.hour.toString();
          optiTijdEind = HourlyResults[i].dateTime.hour.toString();
        } else {
          optiTijdStart = HourlyResults[i - 6].dateTime.hour.toString();
          optiTijdEind = HourlyResults[i + 1].dateTime.hour.toString();
        }
      }
    }
    return [optiTijdStart, optiTijdEind];
  }
}


class WhiteContainersRowOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const WhiteContainersRowOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    OptiTijdCalculator calculator = OptiTijdCalculator();

    double urenContainer1 = 2; // Set the value of "uren" for Container 1
    double urenContainer2 = 7; // Set the value of "uren" for Container 2

    List<String> resultContainer1 =
        calculator.calculateOptiTijd(urenContainer1);
    List<String> resultContainer2 =
        calculator.calculateOptiTijd(urenContainer2);

    return SizedBox(
      width: screenWidth * 0.9,
      height: screenWidth * 0.4,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: screenHeight * 0.30, // main container height
            width: screenWidth * 0.42,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: screenWidth * 0.05),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.local_laundry_service,
                    size: (screenWidth * 0.17),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: screenWidth * 0.02),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Van ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            resultContainer1[0],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Divider(
                        thickness: 2,
                        indent: 48,
                        endIndent: 48,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Tot ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            resultContainer1[
                                1],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth * 0.06,
          ),
          Container(
            height: screenWidth * 0.42,
            width: screenWidth * 0.42,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: screenWidth * 0.05),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.electric_car,
                    size: (screenWidth * 0.14),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: screenWidth * 0.05),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Van ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            resultContainer2[0],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Divider(
                        thickness: 2,
                        indent: 48,
                        endIndent: 48,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Tot ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            resultContainer2[
                                1],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: What is 'HourlyResults'..? it's class isn't it? with result and dateTime variables! where it's coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the `calculateOptiTijd` function. If I add a print statement in that function before doing anything, it does print twice, as we expect.

Looking at your loop:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < HourlyResults.length - 24; i++) {
  List<double> j = [];
  j.add(HourlyResults[i].result);
  if (j.length > uren - 1) {
  ...
```

In each iteration of the loop, you recreate `j` as an empty list and add only 1 (the current) item to it!

As a result, the if statement inside it never triggers (unless `uren <= 0`)

Without knowing what `HourlyResults` is, it's hard to say for certain, but my guess is that this is the issue (i.e. the values of `optiTijdStart` and `optiTijdEind` are never set). Some print statements seem to confirm that with my made-up `HourlyResults`.

#### Next issue

Pulling the declaration of `j` out of the loop reveals another issue to me: if `i` becomes 1 (when `uren` is 2), the condition is met, and we access a negative index in `HourlyResults`. I suggest debugging your function using not only print statements, but perhaps also with some break points to look at the actual values of variables and decision points (if you run in debug mode through Android Studio you should be able to set those, otherwise use Dart DevTools).

#### Some more advice

Unless you plan to do many more things in the `OptiTijdCalculator`, you could just make `calculateOptiTijd` a `static` method or even a top level function. Class instancing doesn't really seem to give you anything in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will definitely follow your advice!